# Custom actions in Thunar: keyboard shortcut already in use

Tags: debian, xfce, thunar

I wanted to add an action in Thunar to open new terminal with `super+T` shortcut. I added a new custom shortcut from `Custom Actions` menu, but it says `keyboard shortcut already in use` when I try to set the keyboard shortcut. I had a custom action with `super+T` shortcut before but I deleted it for now. It seems it didn't delete the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an Actions record in `.config/Thunar/accels.scm` for the deleted custom action:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/uca-action-1561821499974773-1" "<Super>t")
```

I remove this line manually and terminated all Thunar processes and opened Thunar again, and the issue is fixed. I can now use `super+T` on another custom action. I also reported the bug [here](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/546).